# Custom Fields added on Easy Digital Downloads - Frontend Submission form is not saving/updating

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, easy-digital-downloads

I've integrated custom fields using *Advanced Custom Fields* plugin on a submission form created using *Easy Digital Downloads - Frontend Submissions* add-on.

Custom fields display properly on the frontend but don't save/update the value when editing/updating the form. Default form fields work as expected - just custom fields don't work.

As per *Easy Digital Downloads - Frontend Submissions* add-on guidelines, I've added the following hook that integrates the custom fields within the form.

```
add_action('some-hook-name', 'my_modify_dd_form', 10, 3);
function my_modify_dd_form($form_id, $post_id, $form_settings) {
  $args = array(
      'post_id' => $post_id,
      'field_groups' => array(16),
      'form' => false,
      'return' => ''
  );
  acf_form( $args );
}
```

Using the above hook, I am able to populate ACF fields on the frontend – submission form but the values/changes are not saving/updating even though added `acf_form_head();` in the template header.

More on *Frontend Submissions - Form Builder Acton Hooks* can be read at https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/962-frontend-submissions-form-builder

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to fix this myself.

As I've set the form option to false, I had to manually process the ACF fields (by checking the post variables) and update the field values using the ACF function `update_field`.

Eg.

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['acf']['field_5ecb0c4663b4r'] ) ) {
    $mood = $_POST['acf']['field_5ecb0c4663b4r'];
    update_field( 'field_5ecb0c4663bf7', $mood, $post_id );
}
```

`wp_ajax_fes_submit_submission_form` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_fes_submit_submission_form` are the hooks that handles *Easy Digital Downloads - Frontend Submissions add-on*'s form submission process.

I hope this will help someone looking for a similar solution.